# Is there a way to change the order of tabs in Foxit Reader?

Tags: foxit-reader

In web browsers you can drag the tabs to change the order. But I can't do that in Foxit Reader (version 3.1.4.1125, using Windows Vista Home, Chinese Traditional)

Example: I open 3 files:

```
 Page2.pdf
 Page3.pdf
 Page1.pdf
```

which opens Foxit Reader with a tab for each file, in the order

```
 Page2.pdf      Page3.pdf       Page1.pdf
```

Is there a way to change the order of the tabs to

```
 Page1.pdf      Page2.pdf       Page3.pdf
```

?

This would *really* be helpful when you have many files open...

TIA!
Harold

Comment: I've gotten burned by this myself, IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

In the later versions of Foxit Reader you are able to drag the tabs around in the order you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it should be pretty basic / standard functionality, as it is standard for almost every other program that has Tabs for multiple open documents, very annoying that this simple intuitive action does not work.  FYI Running Version: 9.7.0.29455

As an alternative solution, you can drag out a tab into a new window, then drag the tabs from the original window to the new window in the order you want them to appear.  good for a once off, but not if you want to shuffle the order again at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the files in the order of the tabs you want.  There is no way to reorder  the tabs.  The feature has been requested but doesn't seem to be in Reader as of 3.14.

http://forums.foxitsoftware.com//showthread.php?t=14364

Comment: Thanks Joesph. Hopefully there will be an update soon... I'm going to write Foxit support. I'll post if I get an answer. 
BTW, I tried to go to the link you suggested, but it was down (& still is at the moment): 
"Sorry, the board is unavailable at the moment while we are testing some functionality."
So I kept searching without finding an answer, but came across the superuser site and made a post.